# How to use qpdf via latexmk?

Tags: tools, latexmk

In the manual of [latexmk](http://ctan.org/pkg/latexmk) I read that

> [latexmk] can also, if needed, call an external program to do other
>   postprocessing  on  the  generated files.

How can I call [qpdf](http://qpdf.sourceforge.net/) with latexmk? I want to do `qpdf --linearize` on the file that latexmk is operating on. Preferably latexmk will call qpdf only when it is called with a specific flag such as `-l`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The possibility of postprocessing mentioned in the latexmk documentation is only for dvi and postscript files.  (See the description of the `-dF` and `-pF` options, and of the configuration variables `$dvi_filter` and `$ps_filter`.)  I need to correct the documentation on this point.  I could improve latexmk to also do this for pdf files.

But there is a simpler and more general method.  Just define the `$pdflatex` command to include the invocation of qpdf.  For example, you could put the following in one of latexmk's initialization files:

```perl
$pdflatex = 'pdflatex %O %S && qpdf -linearize %D tmp.pdf && mv tmp.pdf %D';
```

(This is in a form suitable for Unix-like operating systems, it will need to be changed for MS-Windows, probably.)  When latexmk uses this, it executes the pdflatex command; if successful it invokes qpdf, putting the result in a temporary file; if that is successful the temporary file is moved to replace the originally generated pdf file.

I don't have qpdf installed on my computer, so I am working from its documentation to write a suitable invocation of it.

If you want a command line option to control the use of qpdf, put the above line in its own file, e.g., useqpdf.  Then you can invoke latexmk to read this file when needed:

```
latexmk -r useqpdf foo.tex
```

Comment: I tested both the approach of changing `$pdflatex` in a configuration file and invoking a file via the `-r` option and both work as expected. It would be more elegant if it was possible to configure options for an arbitrary flag in the configuration file instead of having to remember the correct path for the `-r` flag. (Of course this could be fixed with shell hacks.)

Comment: The problem with this approach is that you run the postprocessing as many times as you run `pdflatex`. It would be nice to be able to apply it only to the final `.pdf`, after the citations and references are resolved.